# How to improve Woocommerce WP_List_Table::display performance from 5-15secs?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, webserver, mariadb

I have a WordPress WooCommerce site with 3.500 products and total 100 custom attributes (usually 4-7 per product) (front page needs image optimization) (4MB total size). Servers frequently lags delaying page response 10+sec. (I don't know if it has to do with the problem or is just php opcache, if I try to run a php echo 'test' and afterwards change it to echo 'test2' the url will give me test instead of test2).

There are 5-6 people using the admin dashboard (all from 1 connection with 5mbps download / 0.7mbps upload).

When 5-6 people using the site it starts to show huge delay (10+sec). I am looking how to spot the error or identify the bottleneck/problem.

**RAM:** Only 2GB used from 32 GB (seen htop monitor image)
nginx error logs warnings/errors about some WooCommerce deprecated functions
also some times browser console report unable to load admin-ajax.php
Error log get like 20MB in one day with deprecation errors.

**Update PHP LOG files was reporting the whole time**

```
[09-May-2018 22:06:28] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (15), consider raising it
[09-May-2018 21:19:52] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 5 idle, and 14 total children
```

I have increase children to 150 min_spare 17 startup 35 max_spare 50,
but still when I refresh page at edit.php (admin dashboard) I have 4.83s waiting

```
Queued at 0
Started at 0.20 ms
Resource Scheduling     TIME
Queueing    
​
0.20 ms
Connection Start        TIME
Stalled 
​
1.27 ms
DNS Lookup  
​
0.53 ms
Initial connection  
​
45.20 ms
Request/Response        TIME
Request sent    
​
31 μs
**Waiting (TTFB)     4.83 s**

Content Download    
​
287.13 ms
```

Spec:

- 8 cores: 4200 bogomips each one
- Nginx with PHP7.2-fpm
- Mariadb innodb tables

[error.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1347MBT7Qmvj4VR09IJBJ2fyu-vebQiWe)

Photos of htop, access log on the end:

[image: htop]

[image: server graph]

[image]

Config:

```
NGINX config
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_temp_path /var/tmp;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    #access_log off;
    #error_log off;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 6;
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

### Update 1

If I an not logged in the site respond TTFB in 30ms (loaded fully in 1-3 secs). If I am logged in the site respond TTFB in 5000ms (loaded fully in 7-9 secs).

### Update 2

If everything (plugins) is enabled any page related to WooCommerce products will have a TTFB response delay of 4-6 secs. unrelated pages (Contact, General settings, Posts, Pages, plugin installation will have low TTFB (800ms-1200ms)

If I deactivate all the plugins the TTFB goes down to 500ms 0.5sec. If I enable any plugin except Woocommerce the TTFB will be 500-700ms.

If I disable all the plugins and I enable only the Woocommerce and try to access product list the page will delay TTFB 5sec (+loading content).

I have build my own child theme based on storefront. If I change active theme, WooCommerce still have the same malfunction (5sec TTFB waiting on product list).

If I am in anonymous Chrome tab (not logged in) and I refresh, the page loads quickly. I have Nginx, PHP opcache and w3 total cache enabled (if I purge cache the anonymous session will need TTFB 5 sec to load a page with products).

I have also tried a fresh WordPress install. Download only the WooCommerce with storefront and copy the database from live site. The problem persist (if you try look the products list in admin dashboard you get 4sec TTFB waiting response).

Thanks to a commenter below, I have installed Newrelic. parse_query 2.0 millions in less than 30 mins:

[image]

[image]

**Update 3 WP_List_Table::display which contains products take too much time to be executed**

Could the cause of the delay be the php printing? and Database queries related to product (see update3)

wp-admin/edit.php (woocommerce products list)
template-homepage (contains 2 slideshow of products)
Archive product (contains list of product+ woof -> attribute filter plugin)
single page product also some delay

On admin I get in broswer console error for [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #in-product_cat-99:

The database query are 14-30ms each but on the web transaction trace it is visible that printing the products (WP_List_Table::display) takes too much time.

How can I fix this? Is it bad php configuration? bad code? sql bad configuration?

PHP config: [link with all my files (nginx php mariadb)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xkh_eRha2cVRVbZLlGyBg2l-dgGSl683)

Images of newrelic report:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How's your mysql server stats ? Are you sure you are not exhausting the database connections or that isn't the database itself causing this issue ?

Comment: Hello Josedasilva, mysql running on same server. how can i get stats?

I am not sure where to look for it might be the mysql (from the beginning I thought about sql i enabled innodb)

Also i just saw on php log file (not nginx) the whole day php reporting
[09-May-2018 22:06:28] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (15), consider raising it

Comment: For the max_children_setting, 15 seems way too low. Here's a good link on how you can calculate the ideal number that matches your requirements.

https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/adjusting-child-processes-for-php-fpm-nginx/

If you increase and doesn't solve it out, will try another things.

Comment: I have increased to 150 (added an update in main comment). htop shows
NI =-1 to all php-fpm and to icbin
now i can say site load slower even with only me using it (previously it would be super fast when 1-2 users and slow when 5-7 users admins start using it) what other things i could see?
TTFB is 4sec . 4sec waiting to get the request :/ - P3 pofile plugin reported that needs 150 sql query to load a page.

Comment: Have you thought about using a monitoring tool to help you on this? I would suggest you to use a NewRelic trial, gives you a great depth on performance (app and server).

https://newrelic.com

It's a 10min setup with instant results.

Comment: Yes thats why i used htop xD to see any result. Thank you for the suggestiosn i will install it asap.
PS!!! If i visit the site log off it respond asap (TTFB 30ms instead of 5sec as logged in admin)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170722/discussion-between-josedasilva-and-john-papadopoulos).

Comment: Where you make updates to a Stack Overflow question, please ensure that it is readable for new readers. Updates at the start are essentially in reverse time order, which is distracting for readers who may be reading this in six months to learn something. Put all updates in the correct order (i.e. at the end) or merge them in to the existing question (if it makes sense to do so _and_ it does not confuse your current readers).

Comment: @JohnPapadopoulos - Find the SQL statement that is taking 8 seconds.  Then we can discuss how to speed it up.

Comment: @josedasilva - Increasing max_children may lead to the queries stumbling over each other -- throughput stalls, and latency suffers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the slow query?

```
SELECT  t.*, tt.*, tm.meta_value
    FROM  wp_terms AS t
    INNER JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
              ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    INNER JOIN  wp_term_relationships AS tr
              ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN  wp_termmeta AS tm
              ON ( t.term_id = tm.term_id
             AND   tm.meta_key = ? )
    WHERE  tt.taxonomy IN (?)
      AND  tr.object_id IN (?)
    GROUP BY  t.term_id
    ORDER BY  tm.meta_value+? ASC,
              t.name ASC
```

Why the `GROUP BY`?  It is 'wrong' not to `GROUP BY` all the non-aggregate columns in the `SELECT` clause.  You will get unpredictable values for the other columns.

Filtering (`WHERE`) on two different tables (tt and tr) makes it difficult for the Optimizer to know which table to start with.

Do you really need all columns (`*`) of `t` and `tt`?  Asking for a limited set of columns *may* speed up the query and/or may provide extra optimization options.

If the Optimizer decides to start with `tt`, then these indexes are needed:

```
tt:  (taxonomy)
t:   (term_id)
tr:  (term_taxonomy_id)
tm:  (term_id, meta_key)
```

If it starts with `tr`:

```
tr:  (object_id, term_taxonomy_id)
plus most of the above
```

Add all those indexes if they don't already exist.

If it won't let you add an index on `meta_key`, there are several options.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

That link gives other performance advice on "many:many" mapping tables based on WordPress.  I assume that `wp_termmeta` is such a table.  Maybe some of the others are, too?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the 4 tables, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if you want to discuss this further.